# IGNORE THIS! Exactly how does one establish the WordPress root directory path?

Tags: wordpress, zoomify

Okay, I managed to sort it out. This is quite a messy post so perhaps it should just be deleted. Ta ....

---

This issue has been dealt with numerous times here but unfortunately, all the responses are code snippets with no instructions on how to use them. Perhaps this forum is too sophisticated for such basic stuff and if I am in the wrong place, any suggestions on where to go would be appreciated.

I have to install a Zoomify folder into the Wordpress root folder for my website. Using cPanel it appears quite straightforward - the root folder seems to be public_html/ - that's where the wp-login.php stuff is. My website folder is one level down and I have put the folder in both locations and fiddled with the path accordingly. All to no avail ... I can't get the Zoomify images up.

I have also gone the other way to the limit being setting up the path as home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx. Still to no avail.

Part of the code referencing the folder looks like this (I can't include the script here):

#heic1403a { width: 650px; height: 500px }

Z.showImage("heic1403a", "/Zoomify5/images/heic1403a", "zSkinPath=/Zoomify5/Assets/Skins/Default", "zLogoVisible=0");

So, could someone kindly instruct me on how to establish the actual root? Replies would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you writing this code? You're right that the absolute root is `/home/xxxxx/public_html/`

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said it's all sorted but for anyone's reference, the Wordpress root is indeed home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx  but public_html/xxxx akso works in this instance. The Zoomify code gets inserted into the actual page or post where you want the image displayed. However, let me rather just set up a new topic titled "Zoomify" and explain it all there.